# How can I get a SwiftUI View to completely fill its superview?

Tags: swift, swiftui

The following is *supposed* to create a `Text` whose bounds occupy the entire screen, but it seems to do nothing.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("foo")
            .relativeSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
            .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

The following hack:

```
extension View {
    /// Causes the view to fill into its superview.
    public func _fill(alignment: Alignment = .center) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            return self.frame(
                width: geometry.size.width,
                height: geometry.size.height,
                alignment: alignment
            )
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("foo")
            ._fill()
            .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

seems to work however.

Is this a SwiftUI bug with `relativeSize`, or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried placing your content in a `ZStack`? Create the background view - `Rectangle`, `Image`, whatever - and then placing your other views on it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to watch [WWDC 2019 Session 237: Building Custom Views with SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/237/), because Dave Abrahams discusses this topic, and uses `Text` in his examples.

To restate briefly what Dave explains in detail:

1. The parent (in this case, a root view created by the system and filling the screen) proposes a size to its child.
2. **The child chooses its own size**, consuming as much or as little of the proposed size as it wants.
3. The parent positions the child in the parent’s coordinate space based on various parameters including the size chosen by the child.

Thus you cannot force a small `Text` to fill the screen, because in step 2, the `Text` will refuse to consume more space than needed to fit its content.

`Color.red` is different: in step 2, it just returns the proposed size as its own size. We can call views like this “expandable”: they expand to fill whatever space they're offered.

`ZStack` is also different: in step 2, it asks its children for their sizes and picks its own size based on its children's sizes. We can call views like this “wrapping”: they wrap their children tightly.

So if you promote `Color.red` to be the “main” view returned by `body`, and put the `Text` in an overlay, your `ContentView` will behave like `Color.red` and be expandable:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.red
            .overlay(Text("foo"))
    }
}
```

If you use a `ZStack` containing both `Color.red` and `Text`, the `ZStack` will wrap the `Color.red`, and thus take on its expandability:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
            Text("hello")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work. The ZStack also will take size from the content. One way is to set the frame using .frame modifier.

Comment: I have fixed my answer and tested it.